# Alternative to using a bearing on threaded rod?

Tags: bolts, product-recommendation

I have a project where I use a threaded rod to allow a piece to move up and down the rod when rotated (much like a deodorant stick) now I need to fix the threaded rod to it's container in such a way that still allows the rod to rotate but not allow it to move any other way. My idea is to use a bearing between the rod and the container. The only way I can think to do so would be to weld the bearing to the rod. Is a simpler way or an already made piece of hardware to do this sort of thing?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How is this a Home Improvement question?

Comment: Don't weld bearings, you'll distort them and wreck the metallurgy of the races. Since it's threaded rod anyway, why not just put a nut above and below the bearing race and run them down to clamp it?  Mill their edge down on a mill if they're too large diameter.  Bonus points for Nyloks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a thrust bearing in the container and then, on the rod you can put a washer followed by two nuts.  Tighten the nuts against each other so they don't move.  Or maybe a nylock nut.

Assuming I'm understanding your question right.